# Getting quotient and modulus at the same time in C#

Tags: c#, math

In C#, one can easily get the quotient and modulus of an integer division:

```
var quotient = 7 / 3;
var modulus = 7 % 3;
```

However, as far as I can tell it doesn't have a `divmod` function, allowing you to get both at once.  Is there a way to do this?  Getting them separately would seem to require the divison to be done twice, unnecessarily, as the processor surely provides both values at the same time for one division.

Comment: In C++, a good compiler would detect that and do the right thing. Don't know about C#

Comment: @ThomasWeller [apparently not](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHunGBLAHYYGAWWwCArtgA2AET4A3AEox8ACkHCEaBpoYBPHRAnC9UAJQcuPG1AYBeBggYBSAwG5rN7sQDsThgB6Dy8GAF9Q0PpdIQYAIQk+aQxBeWVVDVjtGOFDBmNTWIsram8eP1FsDAALADo0lXVsvIKGC09SngjqMKA==) (another Fun Fact is that apparently `Math.DivRem` does not use remainder output of `idiv`, it takes the quotient and then manually computes the remainder with an extra `imul` and `sub`)

Comment: @harold: so that'll be one reason why C++ is still around and people stick to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Math.DivRem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Math.DivRem)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-7.0) to get both the quotient and the remainder.

```cs
var quotient = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, out var remainder);
```